# AWS - Generating presigned url using S3 TransferManager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to generate a presigned url for the data object that I am uploading to the s3 bucket using S3 TransferManager. But I am getting the below error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
    <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
    <Key>mykey</Key>
    <RequestId>9BB78BBE144063EA</RequestId>
    <HostId>myhostid</HostId>
</Error>
```

If I use the com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3 to upload my data object I can generate the pre-signed url successfully. But I would like to use TransferManager as upload performance is far better as compared to AmazonS3 (near to 100 times in my case)
Here is the code that gives me the above error

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                            .withRegion(region.getName())
                            .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
                            .build();
    TransferManager manager = TransferManagerBuilder
                                .standard()
                                .withS3Client(s3Client)
                                .build();
    byte[] zippedBytes = compressLayers(layers); //here the compressed json is got
    ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata();
    metaData.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE_JSON);
    metaData.setContentEncoding(CONTENT_ENCODING_GZIP);
    metaData.setContentLength(zippedBytes.length);
    manager.upload(bucketName, uuidFileName, new ByteArrayInputStream(zippedBytes), metaData);
    java.util.Date expiration = new Date(new Date().getTime()+1000*60*2);
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest req = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, uuidFileName)
                                        .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                                        .withExpiration(expiration);
    URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(req);
```

In the above code if I user the s3Client to upload the data object,

```
s3Client.putObject(bucketName, uuidFileName, new ByteArrayInputStream(zippedBytes), metaData);
```

then it returns the pre-signed url correctly. Also is there any way to generate the pre-signed url using the TransferManager?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: were you able to figure out if there is a way to use pre-signed url with transfer manager?

Comment: unfortunately not